# Get Request Body as String in WebApi Core ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.0

The following is my ActionFilter in a WebApi .Net Core 2 project:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RequestLoggingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        var request = actionContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var route = request.Path.HasValue ? request.Path.Value : "";
        var requestHeader = request.Headers.Aggregate("", (current, header) => current + $"{header.Key}: {header.Value}{Environment.NewLine}");
        request.EnableRewind();
        var requestBody = new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

`requestHeader` has correct value and it's OK, but `requestBody` is always empty.
I test it with sending requests with the following body to an action.

```
[
 {
  "TrackingCode": "96003445",
  "Description": "",
  "InnerMessage": "",
  "Status": 11
 },
 {
  "TrackingCode": "96003840",
  "Description": "",
  "InnerMessage": "Inner message",
  "Status": 11
 }
]
```

How can I get request body in WebApi Core 2 ActionFilter?

Comment: Check position in stream and see if it needs to be reset to 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339283/webapi-get-the-post-raw-body-inside-a-filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With @Nkosi guide I could find the solution as the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RequestLoggingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        var request = actionContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var route = request.Path.HasValue ? request.Path.Value : "";
        var requestHeader = request.Headers.Aggregate("", (current, header) => current + $"{header.Key}: {header.Value}{Environment.NewLine}");
        var requestBody = "";
        request.EnableRewind();
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            stream.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            requestBody = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine

Comment: Seems like later versions of ASP.NET Core have replaced "request.EnableRewind()" with "request.EnableBuffering()". FYI.